# group users by message last sent

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table with messages sent from 1 user to another . I would like to know all messages sent or received from different users not the same .Ex: 1-2   is same as 2-1 but since 2 has made the last contact to user that message will be shown on top and also the name of the user to whom the message is sent or received from other than myself .ALso check if any message is sent from same user like 1-1  .I need to get the name too.   I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

code

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sender varchar(255),
receiver varchar(255),
 msg varchar(255),
 date timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sno varchar(255),
name varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver,msg,date ) VALUES
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:13:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:14:09'),
('2', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:15:09'),
('2', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:16:09'),
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:17:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:18:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:19:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:10:09'),
('3', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:21:09'),
('3', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:22:09'),
('3', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:24:09'),
('3', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:25:19'),
('1', '3', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:26:29'),
('1', '3', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('2', '3', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:28:09'),
('2', '3', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:29:09'),
('1', '2', 'check3 ...','2011-08-21 14:23:09');


INSERT INTO tblB (sno, name ) VALUES
('1', 'Aa'),
('2', 'Bb'),
('3', 'Cc');
```

I am looking on the lines of SMS inbox msgs where data comes/sent to different user and that name along with the last msg sent is displayed.How do I group that?

like this:

http://jesperbylund.com/wp-content/uploads//2011/11/Facebook-Messenger-459x900.png

---

I want the list of people Aa is talking to ordered by Date.

```
Bb
Cc
```

everything apart from Aa as he is the user.

Comment: Please add all relevant info directly into your question. Especially SQLFiddle tends to be down sometimes and we want to preserve posts for future visitors.

Comment: What would the desired result set look like?

Comment: Something on these lines http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19ea8/45

Comment: like this http://jesperbylund.com/wp-content/uploads//2011/11/Facebook-Messenger-459x900.png

Comment: Just paste the desired result set into the question.

Comment: @Jason . . . What more do you want to do beyond the query in SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Hi Gordon.btw nothing is wrong with query in SQL FIDDLE but what I want is different. I am getting data for condition where receiver OR sender is ='1' in this case the user.What I want is ::::::::If the user is 1 the I need receiver's name and if receiver is 1 I need sender's name.Thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you want, but try this:

```
SELECT t1.sender, t1.receiver, MAX(t1.date)
FROM tblA t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tblA ) t2 ON t1.sender = t2.sender 
                                    AND t1.receiver = t2.receiver 
                                    AND t1.sender <> t2.receiver
 GROUP BY t1.sender, t1.receiver
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you need exactly, but you need to use LEFT JOIN to get the name.

It is something like this

```
SELECT a.msg AS message, b.name AS sender, c.name AS receiver, date FROM tblA a
LEFT JOIN tblB b ON b.sno = a.sender
LEFT JOIN tblB c ON c.sno = a.receiver
WHERE a.sender != a.receiver
ORDER BY date DESC
```